# Summing the command line

Tags: c, command-line, atoi, argc

Pretty straightforward, I am trying to sum all of the integers input in the command line. The sum actually works, if I start the program with " 1 1 1 1 " input, the sum increments by one four times. The problem is that sum is initialized at some really large number (4293283588). Why is that?

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
  int a = 0;
  int sum = 0;
  size_t i = 0;

  for (i=0; i<argc; i++)
  {
     a = atoi(argv[i]);
     sum = sum + a;
     printf("%ld\n", sum);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the function definition of `notAtoi`?

Comment: my mistake, it is functionally the same as atoi

Comment: `i=0` --> `i=1` at for, `int sum = 0;` --> `long sum = 0;`

Comment: Hey Broaj, please do not delete your questions such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822575) without a very good reason. This kind of behaviour might get you banned from this site if it repeats.

Answer (score 4):

`argv[0]` is perhaps the name of the executable. From the standard:

> **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**
>
> ....
>
> If the value of **`argc`** is greater than zero, the string pointed to by **`argv[0]`**
>   represents the *program name*; **`argv[0][0]`** shall be the null character if the
>   program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of **`argc`** is
>   greater than one, the strings pointed to by **`argv[1]`**
> through **`argv[argc-1]`**
>   represent the *program parameters*.

Try

```
for (i=1; i<argc; i++)
```

---

Also, as **@BLUEPIXY** indicated, `%ld` assumes type `long`. So either change it to `%d`, or use `long sum`.

Comment: this is correct. `argv` is the full command used to launch the executable, unprocessed except to tokenize by whitespace.

Comment: aaah okay. I was unaware what argv[0] was. I understand now.

Comment: @Woodrow No, it's actually implementation defined. `— argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.
— If the value of argc is greater than zero, the array members argv[0] through
argv[argc-1] inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given
implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup. The
intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup`